# Increase Heap Size Weka

Tags: weka

I know that this question has been asked multiple times before, and most of you who provided an answer to the question of how to increase the heap size have said that you cannot use command line interface to do this but that you have to get into RunWeka.ini and change max heap size= 1024M to max heap size = 2048 M. However, when I try to save the changes I made to RunWeka.ini, I get warning saying access to this fie is denied. I tried viewing it on Notepad and saving it, but access was denied, I tried it on Textpad, but access denied. is there ANY way to increase heap size?

Comment: possibly the file you are editing is being used by some process, try to terminate that process from task-manager and then edit the file.

Answer (score 4):

You can increase the heap size of the tool weka using the terminal.
Run this command on the terminal. It will increase the heap size of the tool weka.

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar weka.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Run as administrator first. In windows, right click on notepad, run as administrator, then you can open RunWeka.ini, modify it and save the changes.

Comment: I know this question is old but it's the only thing that actually worked for me easily, so thanks for that! Couldn't run the .ini as administrator directly

Answer (score 1):

On Debian, `sudo vi /usr/bin/weka` and change the `MEMORY='256m'` to `MEMORY=1024m'`

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the first Google-Result for Stack-Overflow:

what worked for me, on Ubuntu 20.04 with weka 3.8.6

open the weka.sh file and change `MEMORY=` to `MEMORY="4096m"`

then run weka.sh

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but what I did was to first cut the weka.ini file to another location on my pc, changed the maxheap size to my desired size and save before returning it to the weka folder. Guess what? it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your terminal:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar weka.jar
```

in this section.
Or open this file in notepad(run as administrator) from the installation file of Weka as

```
C:\Program Files\Weka-3-9
```

then run RunWeka configuration file then go ...

```
# the heap size (or any other JVM option)
#javaOpts=%JAVA_OPTS%
javaOpts=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xmx1024m
```